# Computer crash/freeze/ no reboot/ (BSOD)

Tags: boot, freeze, bsod, crash, power

I have a hardware issue I'm unable to identify. Thankfully I have a lot of useful symptoms for the sake of diagnosis!

The computer may work fine for many days on end, shouldering heavy workloads without batting an eye, but may without warning become flaky in the morning (always the morning for some reason).

This flakyness might involve freezes (everything looks fine, but doesn't respond to any sort of input), power cuts, or BSODs (two messages so far are IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and BAD_POOL_HEADER). The scans that the BSODs attempt to perform never advance beyond 0%.

The third symptom of doom is the computer not being able to boot (will emit single short beep and have power cut). Turning off and on again doesn't solve the problem, but turning it off, unplugging for about 10 minutes, and turning back on does.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: which operating system are you using? Motherboard model? How many RAM slots are being used?

Comment: @TechieGossip  1) Windows 8.1 (64 bit), 2) err... Dell?, 3) 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't scans, actually. When Windows "blue-screens" like that it usually tried to record a copy of memory to the hard drive before restarting so you have something to inspect to try to find the problem.

That combined with the fact that it never gets past 0% and your second error message may give you a lead. BAD_POOL_HEADER is associated with defective/failing physical RAM. If the RAM was malfunctioning attempting to access it for a memory dump could potentially hard-lock the system... causing the memory dump to freeze in place.

The morning bit takes a bit of a stretch but... the process of the RAM warming up could be triggering the fault. Though RAM heats up pretty quick when in use to you'd likely see the problem not long after you turned the computer on each morning. If you make heavier use of the RAM (some games, photo/video manipulation, etc) in the morning that could also explain it.

Failing RAM also would explain the inability to boot up intermittently. When you pull the power and let it sit the residual charge in all those transistors dissipates and they reset. If a transistor or 1000 in the RAM is stuck (not entirely unlike a stuck pixel on an LCD) depriving it of power for 15+ minutes may be the only way to unstick them. It only takes one transistor getting stuck to cascade errors through Windows until it can't handle it and "blue-screens."

To confirm this I suggest using a RAM test utility. [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) contains a number of useful utilities, among them memtest86+. You download the iso and use your favorite cd burning software to [burn the iso disk-image to a CD-R](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/201431en). Then put the CD-R back in and restart your computer with it in the drive... hopefully your system is already [set up to boot optical-disks](http://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc) (most are these days). Then just go to memory diagnostics and find memtest86+. Run that one morning when you don't need the computer for anything... let it run all morning till at least midday. If it never reports anything then your RAM is fine. If it does report problems replace your ram. If the computer locks up or reboots while running the test that's a major red flag that the RAM is squirrely... but it could be something adjacent to RAM as well.

If any of this makes you even a little uncomfortable I'd suggest taking your computer to a professional tech. Also, techs have the advantage of having compatible parts on hand to perform trial-and-error diagnostics with (still the most reliable method). Trying to solve by trial and error from home can get expensive and tends to be a bit wasteful.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a RAM problem (just wanted to make sure it wasn't confirmation bias as I'd much rather that than a failing motherboard). Will try memtest86+, already tried mdsched.exe but it failed to complete (which indeed may be a red flag)

Comment: it could be the motherboard if it's a voltage issue with the memory bus, but these days the memory controller is actually part of the CPU. Either could potentially cause ram-failure-like issues. But the Ram itself failing is more likely. I think you're on the right track.